# How to downgrade Java version in Mac system?

Tags: java, flutter, macos, android-studio, java-runtime-compiler

I am using mac and inside mac using Android Stuidio, I have done all setup and now My project requires Java version 11 but currently I have Java version 17.

I have checked Java version with this command as : **java --version** and it gives me below output in terminal :

> openjdk 17.0.6 2023-01-17
> OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b829.9-10027231)
> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b829.9-10027231, mixed mode)

How can I change this to:

**openjdk 11.0.20.1 2023-08-24**

I have tried explain my issue and expecting the solution for that.

Comment: install a second jdk and configure your ide to use that

Comment: @Stultuske How to install, can you please guide? I need to use it inside Android Studio.

Comment: If you need Java 17 for other projects, jenv works great to manage multiple java versions https://github.com/jenv/jenv

Answer (score 2):

### Install another JDK

You can install multiple JDKs on your Mac. You can have a [JDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Development_Kit) for [Java 11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_11) as well as a JDK for [Java 17](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_17). And perhaps you might want another JDK for the new [Java 21](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_21) that arrived yesterday. These can all live together, side-by-side.

Each JDK is just a folder full of files. **You can add JDKs, and delete JDKs, at will.**

The [environment variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) `JAVA_HOME` is a hint various software as to which JDK you would like to use by default.

You might find a feature within [*Android Studio*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Studio) to install another JDK. (At least the sibling product, IntelliJ, offers such a feature.)

#### Configure project

Within your project in *Android Studio*, you need to set some settings to indicate which of your installed JDKs should be used for compiling, building, and executing your app. See the *Android Studio* [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio).

#### *SDKMAN!*

Personally, I find it easiest to install [SDKMAN!](https://sdkman.io/), a bunch of [shell scripts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_script) that manage installing/uninstalling JDKs (and other such kits). This works well on [macOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS).

SDKMAN! is designed to be utterly simple to use.

On a console such as [*Terminal.app*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_(macOS)), execute:

- `sdk list java`
  See a list of all JDK products from vendors who chose to submit their data to the SDKMAN! database. From this list you copy the exact name of the JDK product you want to install. The list of products indicates any you have currently installed.
- `sdk install java product_name_goes_here`
  Install the JDK product of your choosing. Takes a moment to download and install. At the end, SDKMAN! prompts you to specify whether you want to make this newly installed JDK the default.
- `sdk uninstall java product_name_goes_here`
  Removes that particular JDK product from your Mac.